Streaming pending transactions
How can you stream pending transactions for a specific mint adress?
I want to monitor pending transactions with datas like adress, amount, confirmations. etc . In python or js .
I imported solders for py and solana/web3.js for js but i only could get conpleted transactions, not the pending ones.
Could someone send me a simple code example to get deeper understanding ?

There is three states transactions can be in: Processed, Confirmed, and Finalized, with Processed being the earliest in the lifecycle of a transaction. More info on what these mean exactly can be found here. When using web3.js, you can specify at what stage of the transaction lifecycle you want to get updates when initializing your connection.
const c = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com","processed");

For getting new signatures for an address though, the earliest confirmation level that you can query signatures for is unfortunately confirmed.
const s = c.getSignaturesForAddress(<Your mint pubkey here>, undefined, "confirmed");

